# Slugify when editing an entry

Tags: django

By adding `prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}` to model admin, Django slugifies the `slug` field in **real-time** i.e. as I type in the `title` field, but **only when adding a new entry**.

After the entry is saved and I come back to edit the `title` field, the `slug` field remains unchanged. Overriding the `save()` method is not what I'm looking for because that doesn't provide the **real-time** functionality.

Django documentation says:

> Prepopulated fields aren’t modified by JavaScript after a value has been saved. It’s usually undesired that slugs change (which would cause an object’s URL to change if the slug is used in it).

I understand the rationale behind this however what should I do to           enable it for editing existing entry?

When I look into Django templates and the `prepopulate.js` I can't understand how Django determines whether the target field already has data, or whether I'm adding a new entry or editing an existing one.